# Matplotlib "ValueError: Image size of .... less than 2^16 in each direction" with log scale

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, bar-chart

Toy problem:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = [10, 11, 12, 15]
y = [5, 7, 4, 3]
z = ["a", "b", "c", "d"]

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize = (6, 6))
ax.bar(x, y)

for i, j in enumerate(zip(y, z)):
    plt.text(i + 10, j[0] - 0.3, s = str(j[0]), color = 'white')
    plt.text(i + 10, j[0] + 0.1, s = str(j[1]), color = 'black')

plt.show()
```

This creates a plot, with actual values as text labels, nice stuff. Text labels aren't aligned above each bar though since there's a gap in x values.

[image: first plot]

No worries, can insert some data:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = [10, 11, 12, 15]
y = [5, 7, 4, 3]
z = ["a", "b", "c", "d"]

x.insert(3, 13)
x.insert(4, 14)
y.insert(3, 0)
y.insert(4, 0)
z.insert(3, ' ')
z.insert(4, ' ')

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize = (6, 6))
ax.bar(x, y)
# ax.set_yscale('log')

for i, j in enumerate(zip(y, z)):
    plt.text(i + 10, j[0] - 0.3, s = str(j[0]), color = 'white')
    plt.text(i + 10, j[0] + 0.1, s = str(j[1]), color = 'black')

plt.show()
```

[image: second plot]

Sweet, just what we wanted, gorgeous plot.

However...

```
# ax.set_yscale('log')
```

If set_yscale('log') is un-commented:

```
ValueError: Image size of 384x806494 pixels is too large. It must be less than 2^16 in each direction.
```

So you can't have a 0 in the y values because log 0 is undefined. Makes sense.

Except now, I can't fix the original problem, since 0 can't be used to represent an empty bar.

log 1 is = 0, but if you insert 1, a bar is still shown, because reasons I guess?

Are there any workarounds for this with matplotlib version '2.2.3'? If 0 can't be used, what can?

Thanks

Comment: This code works fine with a log scale on a modern matplotlib.

Comment: @JodyKlymak That's actually quite upsetting x) I can't update anything on the VM that I need to execute similar code on..

Comment: Did you look at using the `bottom` parameter of `bar`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A workaround would be to log your y-values before plotting and plot on a linear scale:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = [10, 11, 12, 15]
y = [5, 7, 4, 3]
z = ["a", "b", "c", "d"]

x.insert(3, 13)
x.insert(4, 14)
y.insert(3, 0)
y.insert(4, 0)
z.insert(3, ' ')
z.insert(4, ' ')

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize = (6, 6))

mask = ~np.isinf(np.log(y)) # get mask of non-inf values
ax.bar(np.array(x)[mask], np.log(y)[mask]) # plot only non-inf values

for i, j in enumerate(zip(y, z)):
    if not j[0]: # skip 0 values
        continue

    plt.text(i + 10, np.log(j[0]) - 0.08, s=str(j[0]), color='white', ha='center')
    plt.text(i + 10, np.log(j[0]) + 0.02, s=str(j[1]), color='black', ha='center')

plt.show()
```

I had to change the y-values of your text to make it look nice. Have a look at the result below:

[image: resulting plot]

Comment: I would add `plt.text(..., ha="center")` so that texts and bars share the same center.

Comment: @Paddy Harrison I like your solution. But I have issues running it. It might be because I'm running python 2.7, but when I run your code I get: ValueError: cannot convert float NaN to integer

Comment: I got the same error in Python2 too. I edited the answer above to make it work for Python2. It involves masking out the `inf` values and skipping them when plotting text. I hope this helps.

Comment: Also added @Guimoute nice suggestion.

Comment: @PaddyHarrison Beautiful answer mate, didn't even know that was a thing. Thanks a bunch :)